# Engines fire animation for mobile app created in Unity

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, light, import, unity

Folks.
I need some help with creating fire animation and using it for airplane engines in Unity (like an afterburner effect).

[image]

Should I use Cycles for better materials since I already have a pretty nice one? What kind of file format should I use for rendering? If it's .png images and I remove the pure black background that I have I loose all colors of the fire...sad but I don't know why :D. Is it possible to import the whole blender file and edit it there? Also, I have no idea how to make it light for mobile game. And last but not so important - could you give me some hint on how to make the animation repeatable?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way (as far as I know) to bring a Blender particle system into Unity. If you want to use your Blender fire, render out transparent png sequences from all the sides that will be seen in game. Then use planes with with the images in Unity. However, given your knowledge of Unity and Blender, I would recommend you import Unity's free ParticleSystem pack and go from there.